# PHP parse dict output from python script

Tags: python, php

How do I parse a dict output from a python script to a PHP array? My PHP file contains the line `exec('/bin/python ~/somescript.py', $out, $err);`. And my python script prints a dict with something like

```
d = {0: "a", 7: "d", 23: ["e", "z"]}
print(d)
```

But this doesn't work, `$out[0]` in my PHP file is just a really long string an array. I've also tried to use  `print(json.dumps(d))`, same result (but with escaped " ).

Comment: It shouldn't be `json.loads(d)` as `.dumps` is used for encoding a python object to a json string (what I need). And `.loads` is used for decoding a json string to a python object. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: `$out` is the output of the python script. See https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php.

Comment: Great, this worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `print(json.dumps(d))` in your Python script. Trim the `dumps` output by passing it `separators=(',', ':')` with the default `indent=None` so that the JSON is dumped to one line. So:

```py
print(json.dumps(d, indent=None, separators=(',', ':')))
```

After that `json_decode($out)` or `json_decode($out[0])` in your PHP script.